# Can adding 1 to the numerator and denominator on both sides of an inequation change the outcome?

Tags: inequality

I'm computing a fraction from a database when both numerator and denominator can be zero. To solve this problem I thought of adding 1 to each.

I know I can add 1 only to the denominator, but this is for optimization of resources and adding 1 to the denominator favors tasks which have a low denominator.

Because 3/3 == 4/4, but 3/4 > 4/5 and thus the task with 4 will get the resources because the program will think it has more to complete.

This brings me to my question:

If I know that

$\frac{a}{b} > \frac {c}{d}$

Can $\frac{a+1}{b+1} < \frac {c+1}{d+1}$ happen, even once?

The above formula translates to

$a+d > c+b+(bc-ad)$

and this is where I'm stuck.

Comment: This won't be true for suppose $\frac{-2}{5} \gt \frac{-1}{4}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{7}{10}\gt\frac{2}{3}$ but $\frac{8}{11}\lt \frac{3}{4}$

Comment: could you explain how you found this?

Comment: @Hachiloni I restricted myself to positive numbers, just in case those were more useful to you. Then I recalled that adding $1$ to both numerator and denominator in those circumstances brings the fraction closer to $1$ (from below or above - fairly easy to prove rigorously), but, following the intuition as in Yves Daoust's graphical answer, I expected that it will "affect" more the fractions with the smaller numerator/denominator.

Comment: Thus, I had to find a fraction $\gt 1$ with "small" numerator/denominator that is only *slightly* bigger than another one with "large" numerator/denominator - and then check what happens when I add $1$. Pretty much the first pair of fractions I tried worked.

Comment: (My claim from above: let $a,b>0, \frac{a}{b}>1$, i.e. $a>b$. Then $\frac{a+1}{b+1}<\frac{a}{b}$ because $(a+1)b=ab+b<ab+a=a(b+1)$.

Comment: I guess I forgot to limit the question to fractions smaller than 1. I hoped you'd have a formula so I could look at it

Comment: I've edited the answer to provide a sample of fractions $<1$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $a,b,c,d>0$ then we have that

$$\frac{a}{b} > \frac {c}{d} \iff ad-bc>0$$

and

$$\frac{a+1}{b+1} > \frac {c+1}{d+1} \iff ad-cb+a+d-c-b >0$$

which fails when

$$c+b-a-d>ad-cb \iff c+b+bc>a+d+ad $$

that is for example

$$\frac{4}{7}\gt\frac{1}{2}, \quad \frac{5}{8}\lt\frac{2}{3}$$

indeed in this case

$$c+b+bc=1+7+7=15>a+d+ad=4+2+8=14$$

Answer (score 2):

**Answer without words:**

++++++++++

[image]

Comment: Are not "The ticks show one unit" 5 words? :)

Comment: could you explain the graph? What are the colors? what are the axis?
two answers state two different sets, how do I see it here?

Comment: @Hachiloni: I want to leave this answer "without words".

Comment: @user: the editor did not let me write only the title. But I will modify.

Comment: @Hachiloni The small blue triangle has the corners at $(0,0)$, $(b,a)$ and $(b+1, a+1)$. The slope of the sides coming out of $(0,0)$ is, respectively, $\frac{a}{b}, \frac{a+1}{b+1}$, the slope of the third side is $1$. You can see geometrically how the slope is "pushed up" (towards $1$, as it originally was $<1$) when we switch from $(b,a)$ to $(b+1, a+1)$. The same for the green triangle, which is all about $c,d$.

Comment: The main point is, the points on the green triangle are further away from the origin than the ones on the blue triangle, so the slope of the bottom side was bigger on the green triangle *before* the transformation, but is now smaller after the transformation.